# Error con Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch en React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Estoy haciendo una aplicación tipo *Trello* y estoy tratando de cambiar el título a una carta.

Me sale el error:

> Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: lists.0.cards.0.text. Take a look at the reducer(s) handling the action {"type":"EDIT_CARD","payload":{"id":"card-0","listID":"list-0","newText":"adios"}}.

He probado el bucle con el método `map()` con *Javascript Vanilla* y me funciona, pero al implementarlo en mi código de *React* me salta el error.

Este es el archivo donde se edita la carta, recibo los parámetros por la constante TrelloCard:

```
const TrelloCard = ({ text, id, index, listID, dispatch }) => {
const [onTextEdit, setOnTextEdit] = useState(text)

const handleChangeEdit = (e) => {
    setOnTextEdit(e.target.value)
  };

  const saveEdit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(editCardAction(id, listID, onTextEdit));
  };

  const editCard =() => {
    return (
    <div
      <textarea          
        text = {onTextEdit}
        autoFocus
        onChange={handleChangeEdit}
      >
        </textarea>
      <button
        onClick= {saveEdit}
      > Guardar
      </button>          
    </div>
    )
  }
```

Cuando guardamos el texto hacemos *dispatch*. El parámetro que pasamos de "id" es la identidad de la carta, "listID" es la lista en la que se encuentra la carta, "onTextEdit" es el texto nuevo que debemos poner.

En el archivo action realizamos la siguiente acción:

```
export const editCardAction = (id, listID, newText) => {
  return {
    type: 'EDIT_CARD',
    payload : {id, listID, newText}
  }
}
```

En reducer hago dos bucles con map para acceder al texto de la carta que coincida con la "id" dentro de la lista correcta "listID", al acceder al texto lo cambio por newText

Este es el archivo reducer:

```
let cardID = 2;
    let listID = 1;
    const initialState = [
      {
        title: 'lista demo 1',
        id: 1,
        cards: [
            {
                id: 1,
                text: 'Lista tarea1'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                text: 'lista tarea2'
            }
        ]
      },
      
    ];
    
    const listReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
    case 'EDIT_CARD': {      
  const { id, listID, newText} = action.payload;
  console.log(id)
    return state.map((list) => {
      if(list.id === listID) {
        return list.cards.map(({...card}) =>{
          if(card.id === id){
            card.text = newText;
            console.log(card);
          }
          return card
        })
      }
    })
}
    default:
          return state;
    }
```

El plan final es poder cambiar el texto de la tarjeta, pero me da el error ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda, si hace falta algo más de código, diganmelo y lo pondré. Saludos

Comment: Yo no veo que cuando llamas a la funcion le estes pasando el parametro ID ``onClick= {saveEdit}`` ni tampoco veo que lo estes obteniendo de alguna forma

Comment: Buenas de nuevo, es importante para saber lo que está fallando que nos indiques la linea en que falla. En el error te lo tiene que indicar. Ya que el error es que se está intentando acceder a una propiedad de un objeto nullo. También que en el primer console log, añadas state para saber la estructura del estado

Comment: Hola Agustin, los parámetros los llamo al formar el componente, no lo puse aqui por no complicar mucho el codigo, ahora estarán añadidos.

Comment: Hola de nuevo Suso, en el navegador no me dice ninguna línea de error, me saca "bundle.js:821 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')    at bundle.js:821:26".   Todas las referencias a un archivo es hacia este bundle.js.  En la terminal no me da ningún error. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 2 errores, uno "tonto" (no quiero faltarte al respeto, pero es una tontería) y otro en el mapeo del reducer.

1. En el archivo action.js en la accion "editCardAction" un parámetro que recibe es listID y tu tienes ListID con L mayúscula y ese valor es undefined.
2. En el mapeo del reducer:

   ```
    case 'EDIT_CARD': {
       const { id, listID, newText} = action.payload;
       return state.map(({...list}) => {
          if(list.id === listID) {
              const newCards = list.cards.map(({...card}) =>{
                  if(card.id === id){
                     card.text = newText;
                  }
                  return card
              })
              list.cards = newCards;
          }
          return list;
      })
   }
   ```

Antes, si coincidia el id de la lista, con la lista en la que modificabas una card, se retornaba el mapeo de list.cards con los cambios en la card indicada, pero list tenía mas propiedades que la lista, ahora lo que hace es si coincide la lista, se modifica la propiedad cards con el mapeo de las cards con los cambios y luego se retrona la lista coincida el listID o no;

Sugerencia, tienes un error en el reducer del dragghappened. Si cambias la linea que tienes `const newState = [...state]` por esto ya no te pasa

```
  const newState = state.map(({...list}) => {
    list.cards = list.cards.map(({...card}) => card)
    return list;
  })
```

Comment: No se si funciona, el primer codigo si me hace el cambio de texto en la consola, pero la vista se rompe y se queda la pantalla en blanco. El segundo no me cambia el texto. Al romperse me sale este error que tampoco he podido solucionar. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). Gracias por tu ayuda Suso

Comment: Quería editar mi pregunta y sin querer edite la respuesta de Suso, no puedo eliminar ni rechazar esa edición por falta de privilegios, si alguien quisiera hacerlo por mi se lo agradeceria. Perdon por las molestias y gracias.

Comment: Ya he rechazado la edicion de la respuesta. De todas maneras, no se porque no te funciona. En tu código hay un error, ya que en el segundo map no devuelves el objeto card y por lo tanto el valor de cards de esa lista va a ser un array con undefined en lugar de cards. Por eso luego te da error cuando intenta leer una propiead de undefined

Comment: Es extraño, porque cuando hago un console.log(card) al final del código, si me sale el objeto card con el texto cambiado en la consola. Pero la aplicación se rompe y me da el error.

Comment: El problema esta que no devuelve el nuevo estado con el texto cambiado, pero en la consola si lo hace.

Comment: pero le has puesto un return card en el segundo map?

Comment: Si, le retorno card y me salta el error, copie tu primer código tal como me lo dejaste. Me parece que al editar la pregunta no me copio bien el código y por eso no lo viste. Ya lo he cambiado.

Comment: Creo que ya he dado con el problema. En el map siempre hay que devolver algo, si no sustituira los datos por undefined. En el primer map preguntas si los id lista coinciden, si coinciden modificas el texto y luego retornas el nuevo objeto. pero si no coinciden no pusiste que tiene que retornar list

Comment: No, no me funciona. Creo que me voy a rendir y lo voy a dejar unos días, llevo ya muchos días aquí atascado y me estoy frustrando un poco. Gracias por tu ayuda Suso.

Comment: Si tuviera el enlace al repositorio como pusieras de la otra vez, podría hacer pruebas y vería realmente cual es el fallo. Si no quieres compartirlo, pues no pasa nada. Un saludo

Comment: El repositorio es el mismo que la otra vez, https://github.com/jbortweb/trello_react.  Gracias Suso por tu tiempo.

Comment: Ya he editado la respuesta con los fallos que había. A mi me funciona perfectamente. Si tienes algún problema avisa. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias Suso, Lo de los parámetros me di cuenta, pero en alguna de estas revisiones de la pregunta volvi a poner el codigo con el listID en mayúsculas, lo siento. La edición de la carta funciona correctamente, pero si pongo el código del reducer del dragghappened que me has pasado, no se me arrastran los elementos, si lo dejo como estaba funciona correctamente. Se me está atragantando el redux, tengo que reconocer que yo aprendo mejor viendo los ejemplos y a partir de ahí empiezo a atar cabos. Gracias a ti me esta siendo más fácil. Saludos

Comment: En el pc en que estoy ahora no puedo revisar lo del drag, pero me acuerdo de que hacia el final del reducer usas 2 veces la variable `state` y hay que modificarla por `newState`, me olvidé de comentartelo. Con eso debería de funcionar, ya que no te funciona ahora porque en la consola da un error.

Comment: Si que me salta el error de drag and drop, pero me funciona tal y como esta. Ya conseguí finalizar el ejercicio a pesar de ese error, pude editar y borrar las listas en el reducers. Gracias por tu tiempo y paciencia.